# How to identify how contrasts are set in R?

Tags: r, statistics, global-variables

I am looking for a function or code that checks how contrasts are globally set in R at any given moment, so that I can reset it after running some code.

So I'm looking for something like this:

```
# Identify current contrasts
original_contrasts <- get_contrasts() 

# Change contrasts
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))

# Run some models ....

# Reset to original contrasts
options(contrasts=original_contrasts)
```

Does such a function exist?

Comment: `options("contrasts")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `options("contrasts")` to store the current contrasts, which returns:

```
$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

# Identify current contrasts
original_contrasts <- options("contrasts")

# Change contrasts
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
```

The contrasts are now:

```
$contrasts
[1] "contr.sum"  "contr.poly"

# Run some models ....

# Reset to original contrasts
options(contrasts=unname(unlist(original_contrasts)))
```

which again gives you:

```
$contrasts
[1] "contr.treatment" "contr.poly"
```